# HtmlAgilityPack strip html in controller ASP MVC4+

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-agility-pack

I have an index view which return a list of data. The title parameter contains HTML tags. When I load this view, my title like that `<strong>title</strong>.`

But I don't need theses tags in this situation, so I'm trying to remove them only for this view. I have read that operation could be done in controller, could you tell me how to do that with HtmlAgilityPack ?

Controller

```
public ActionResult ArchivePanel(string sortOrder, string currentFilter,string searchString,int? page)
{
...
var alertMap = db.AlertMap.Include(a=>a.AlertLog).Include(a=>a.AlertMode).Include(a=>a.AlertPriority).Include(a=>a.AspNetUsers);
...
return View(alertMap.ToPagedList(pageNumber.pageSize));
}
```

I need to do this operation on a.AlertLog.AlertTitle value

View

```
<td>
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.AlertLog.AlertTitle)
</td>
```

Thanks

Comment: You can simply load the string containing HTML tags to HAP's `HtmlDocument` object, then access `InnerText` property to get only the text content

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you not to use the HtmlAgilityPack for this.  This is for manipulating HTML, and in the controller you should not be changing the raw HTML.

Instead, I would suggest using a different view for your page in this situation, that had the look and feel you need in this context.  You can factor out the parts of the view that are common with the original view into a shared layout.

Comment: I store html tags in the db for this parameter, when a user create a deskalert message. So, when a user read this message later with a wpf client-side application he could have html parsed text. But on the server side application I don't need the tags, when a user list deskalert message. That's why I'm trying to suppress tags only for this view. Is there a more simple way ?